# Multiple thread group execution based on a condition in thread group one

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

I have multiple thread groups(2 thread groups) in which based on the condition one thread group should run, if the condition fails should not run thread group 2.

- Thread group one
- regex -  success
- BeanShell assertion - `${__setProperty(success,${success})};`

Thread group Two if controller - 
`${__jexl3("${success}"== "Save and submit was successful")}`

Expected -  Based on the condition thread group 2 execution flow should run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check value in `props` and use `__groovy` and `equals` for comparing Strings:

```
${__groovy("Save and submit was successful".equals(props.get("success")))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `${success}` expression stands for JMeter Variable while you need to evaluate JMeter Property instead.

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So you need to amend If Controller's condition to include [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__jexl3("${__P(success,)}"=="Save and submit was successful",)}
```

Be informed that you will have to tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` box on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level. In the majority of case it's better to go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/), check out [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) test plan for demo